# "X is not a valid value for the Priority property" BizTalk 2006 R2 to EMS via EMS Adapter

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk, tibco, tibco-ems

I've been working with BizTalk 2006 R2 to send/receive messages to a TIBCO EMS queue. I am using the "Biztalk Adapters for Enterprise TIBCO EMS adapter" to communicate from BizTalk to EMS, and I have the latest service pack.

My orchestration ends by dropping messages into an EMS queue for retrieval by a third party application, unfortunately this is not working. The Application Event Log shows an error from "Microsoft Biztalk Adapter" stating:

`4 is not a valid value for the Priority property`

along with a warning after it from "BizTalk Server 2006":

`The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "SendToEMSPort" with URL "TibcoEMS://localhost_7222_e73cb46d-2c01-4055-b4ec-73e9364489a9". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"1 is not a valid value for the Priority property".`

The message never gets through. I've tried all allowable values of "Priority" (0 through 9) with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a way in Biztalk that you cal tell if you are setting the priority as an integer rather than a string? i.e., it might be complaining that the string "4" is not a valid value...